# Significato di "colpire col diavolo a sette code"

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto la frase seguente:

> Ti trovai come se ti **avessero colpito** in tutto il corpo **col diavolo a sette code**.

La mia domanda è sull'espressione "colpire col diavolo a sette code" che appare in questa frase. Si tratta di un modo di dire? Qual è il suo significato? Ho ricercato su Google, ma non ho trovato nessuna informazione a riguardo.

Answer (score 2):

Penso si riferisca piuttosto al [gatto a nove code](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatto_a_nove_code) che era un mezzo di tortura particolarmente doloroso, usato nella flagellazione.

> Era in uso nell'antichità, tipicamente presso i Romani. Lo strumento
>   era allora costituito da fibbie di cuoio alle cui estremità erano
>   legati artigli metallici, ossa di pecora o palline di piombo, che
>   laceravano in profondità le carni del condannato, tanto che sovente
>   questi non sopravviveva. La definizione di "gatto a nove code" si
>   riferisce di solito più specificamente alla frusta a nove lacci di
>   corda annodati, che veniva usata come punizione sulle navi della
>   marina reale e nell'esercito del Regno Unito.
>
> Questo genere di punizioni corporali vennero ufficialmente bandite in
>   Inghilterra e in altri paesi del Commonwealth solo negli anni
>   successivi al secondo conflitto mondiale anche per i prigionieri ed i
>   non inglesi nelle colonie, mentre l'ultima fustigazione sul suolo
>   della madrepatria di un soldato di nazionalità inglese avvenne nel
>   1831; la pena della frusta resta in uso in altri ordinamenti.

e da [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gatto/):

> 4 d. Gatto a nove code, specie di frusta con nove strisce di cuoio,
>   con cui un tempo in Inghilterra si percoteva il dorso nudo dei
>   delinquenti; lo stesso nome ha indicato anche lo knut.